# How to check if a given number is Fibonacci number?

Tags: php

i am trying to check my numbers is fibonacii or not ?

```
isFibonacci(13);
function isFibonacci( $testedNumber, $a = 1, $b = 1 )
{
    if( $testedNumber == 0 || $testedNumber == 1 )
        return true;//returning true for 0 and 1 right away.
    $nextFib = $a + $b;//getting the next number in the sequence
    if( $nextFib > $testedNumber )
        return false;//if we have passed the tested number, it's not in the sequence
    else if( $nextFib == $testedNumber )
        return true;//if we have a perfect match, the tested number is in the sequence
    else
        isFibonacci( $testedNumber, $b, $nextFib );//otherwise, get the next fibonacci number and repeat.
}
```

Comment: Fibonacci is a series .. are you trying to find that if the given no. can be the part of of that series or not???

Comment: yes it is part of number

Comment: I don't know how it is written in php but you can check-out this site which gives C++ and Python versions: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-number-fibonacci-number/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

function getFibonicciIndex($number)
{
    $log_base = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
    $index = log(($number*sqrt(5)-(1/2)), $log_base);
    return floor($index)+1;
}
function getFibonicciNumber($term)
{
    $a = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
    $b = (1-sqrt(5))/2;
    $fibonicci_number = (pow($a, $term)-pow($b, $term))/sqrt(5);
    return $fibonicci_number;
}
$number = 14;
$index = getFibonicciIndex($number);
$index_value = getFibonicciNumber($index);
echo ($number == $index_value) ? "yes" : "no";
```

//This logic implements the best rule to find the Fibonacci series and their index.  First we suppose the given no. is a part of Fibonacci series and try to get index .. and then for that given index we calculate the Fibonacci number and equate it to verify

Comment: i dont think your implementation is correct, 3 and 5 is Fibonacii  number but is shows No.

Comment: @JunedAnsari  Please recheck .. after your comment i tested for both no. and it shows yes.. and you should check strictly before down-voting any answer

Comment: https://ideone.com/DeX5uc Check this and also post your code so i can see

Comment: Dear M A Siddiqui, i already checked, it is better you check properly from your end then post code.

Comment: it prints no, it should print yes bcoz number 3 is from fibonacii series

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134735/discussion-between-m-a-siddiqui-and-juned-ansari).